# jenkins pipeline execute ssh command in loop

Tags: bash, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a pipeline and want to run a shell script on multiple servers, I am reading list of server from a txt file, I wrote code to iterate over that list and run shell script for each server in that list.

Problem is loop is not going past first execution. If I just print servers name and not execute ssh command it prints all server names, that means loop is working fine but not working as expected with ssh command. I tried for loop as well but same issue.

```
stage('execute script') {
   steps {
        script {

           ....some code here

           def absoluteFilePath = "${WORKSPACE}/serversList.txt"
           def fileContent = readFile(absoluteFilePath)
           listOfServers = fileContent.split('\n')
        }
        iterateOverList(listOfServers, "${WORKSPACE}/")
   }
}

@NonCPS 
def iterateOverList(list, workSpacePath) {
    //iterate over servers list and execute shell script on it.
    list.each { hostServer ->
        sh "ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null' -i /var/lib/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@${hostServer} 'sudo bash -s' <  ${workSpacePath}myShellScript.sh"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are couple of unresolved bugs with groovy closures in Jenkins pipelines, for example [JENKINS-46749](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46749) and [JENKINS-46747](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46747).

So use simple Java loop to iterate over your list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    sh "ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null' -i /var/lib/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@${list[i]} 'sudo bash -s' <  ${workSpacePath}myShellScript.sh"
}
```

Comment: got error: **org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods execute java.lang.String**

Comment: Excuse me, my suggestion about wrong context for Pipeline DSL was completely wrong. Actually, there are bugs with groovy closures in Jenkins pipelines, so I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! @Alexey Prudnikov, but I have mentioned in my question that I have already tried For loop but same result, loop is not going past first iteration. Not sure but could it be that first iteration of ssh command has to return some code to notify that first ssh command executed without errors(just guessing).